# Problem publishing TopologyTestDriver with MockSchemaRegistry

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm facing a problem with the TopologyTestDriver, since is mandatory to set the property: `KafkaAvroSerializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "url"` when the topology is trying to publish the record into the topic, it goes to the "url" provided in the config. How can I mock that access to point to the MockedSchemaRegistry?

To write records in avro to the topic works with `mockSchemaRegistryClient.register`

Also another issue, how can I load a stateStore into the topology? I'm creating the stateStore at the initialization(the topic is already created)

My dependecies:

```
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.1")
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.18.3'
    testCompile 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.9.1'
    testCompile ("org.mockito:junit-jupiter:2.20.0")
    testCompile 'org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:1.5.0'
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version: '5.0.8.RELEASE'
    testCompile 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams-test-utils:2.0.0'
```

Here is my code:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@Import({KafkaStreamsCdlcfMapperConfiguration.class, KafkaStreamsCdlcfMapperSpecificConfiguration.class,
        CdlcfStreamsTopologyImpl.class, CdlcfMappingProcessor.class, CdlcfMappingServiceImpl.class, RecordParserServiceImpl.class,
        FormatFileFromJarImpl.class})
@TestPropertySource(locations = "../application.properties")
public class SyncronizerIntegrationTest {

    String schemaRegistryUrl = "http://mock:8081";

    @Autowired
    private CdlcfStreamsTopology cdlcfStreamsTopology;


    private GenericDatumWriter<GenericRecord> datumWriter;

    MockSchemaRegistryClient mockSchemaRegistryClient = new MockSchemaRegistryClient();

    @Value("${cdlcf-mapper.topics.unmapped-cdlcf}") String unmappedCdlcfTopic;
    @Value("${cdlcf-mapper.topics.mapped-cdlcf}") String mappedCdlcfTopic;
    @Value("${cdlcf.topics.logs}") String logsTopic;

    @Test
    void integrationTest() throws Exception {

        Properties fakeProps = new Properties();
        fakeProps.setProperty(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "streamsTest");
        fakeProps.setProperty(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "dummy:1234");
        fakeProps.setProperty(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        fakeProps.setProperty(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, GenericAvroSerde.class.getName());

        fakeProps.setProperty("value.serializer", KafkaAvroSerializer.class.getName());
        fakeProps.setProperty(KafkaAvroSerializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "url"); //If records are produced will try to register the record in the schemaRegistry

        StreamsBuilder kStreamBuilder = new StreamsBuilder();

        int idSchema = mockSchemaRegistryClient.register(getSubjectName("topic",false),Tracking.getClassSchema());
        Serde<GenericRecord> avroSerde = getAvroSerde(mockSchemaRegistryClient);


        ConsumerRecordFactory<String, String> recordFactory = new ConsumerRecordFactory<>(new StringSerializer(),  new StringSerializer());

        String lineContent="lineContent";



        TopologyTestDriver testDriver = new TopologyTestDriver(cdlcfStreamsTopology.getTopology(),fakeProps);

        testDriver.pipeInput(recordFactory.create(unmappedCdlcfTopic,"CDLCF_20180903_125115009", lineContent));

    }
```

Exception thrown(obviously because no schemaRegistry is started)

```
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Exception caught in 
process. taskId=0_0, processor=KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000002, topic=test, partition=0, offset=0

    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:304)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.TopologyTestDriver.pipeInput(TopologyTestDriver.java:393)

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing Avro message
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1220)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:984)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1334)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1309)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:172)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:229)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:320)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:312)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:307)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.registerAndGetId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:114)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.register(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:153)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:79)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.serialize(KafkaAvroSerializer.java:53)
    at io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerializer.serialize(SpecificAvroSerializer.java:65)
    at io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerializer.serialize(SpecificAvroSerializer.java:38)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:154)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:98)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SinkNode.process(SinkNode.java:89)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:143)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:129)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:90)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamPassThrough$KStreamPassThroughProcessor.process(KStreamPassThrough.java:33)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.runAndMeasureLatency(ProcessorNode.java:244)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:133)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:143)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:122)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamBranch$KStreamBranchProcessor.process(KStreamBranch.java:48)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.runAndMeasureLatency(ProcessorNode.java:244)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:133)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:143)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:126)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:90)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamFlatMap$KStreamFlatMapProcessor.process(KStreamFlatMap.java:42)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.runAndMeasureLatency(ProcessorNode.java:244)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:133)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:143)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:129)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:90)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:87)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:288)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.TopologyTestDriver.pipeInput(TopologyTestDriver.java:393)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, thanks to Matthias, found a working solution, but I will apreciate tips, to improve this workaround. Because I had to add a method just for testing(which I don't like).
The problem, as Matthias pointed out, was the serdes generated inside the topology wasn't pointing to the mocked schema. So i wrote a serdes setter, and setted the "mocked serdes"

Solution code here:

Setter for the topology(would like to change this...)

```
 cdlcfStreamsTopology.setSerdes(trackinSerde, logSerde);
```

Creating the avro serdes with the mocked schema

```
 Serde<Tracking> trackinSerde = getAvroSerde(mockSchemaRegistryClient);
 Serde<Log> logSerde = getAvroSerde(mockSchemaRegistryClient);

private <T extends SpecificRecord> Serde<T> getAvroSerde(SchemaRegistryClient schemaRegistryClient) {

        OwnSpecificAvroSerde serde = new OwnSpecificAvroSerde(schemaRegistryClient,schemaRegistryUrl);
        return serde;
    }
```

I had to create this OwnSpecificAvroSerde in order to pass through the constructor the mockedSchema. For that I had to create a local package with the same name as the avro library, to access to the default class that has the schema constructor.

```
package io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro;

public class OwnSpecificAvroSerde<T extends GenericRecord> extends GenericAvroSerde {

    private String registryUrl;

//    public OwnSpecificAvroSerde(String registryUrl) {
//        this.registryUrl=registryUrl;
//    }
    public OwnSpecificAvroSerde(SchemaRegistryClient schemaRegistryClient,String registryUrl) {
        super(schemaRegistryClient);
    }

    public <T> Serde<T> getAvroSerde(boolean isKey, MockSchemaRegistryClient mockSchemaRegistryClient) {
        return Serdes.serdeFrom(getSerializer(isKey,mockSchemaRegistryClient), getDeserializer(isKey,mockSchemaRegistryClient));
    }

    private <T> Serializer<T> getSerializer(boolean isKey, MockSchemaRegistryClient mockSchemaRegistryClient) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.AUTO_REGISTER_SCHEMAS, true);
        map.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, registryUrl);
        Serializer<T> serializer = (Serializer) new KafkaAvroSerializer(mockSchemaRegistryClient);
        serializer.configure(map, isKey);
        return serializer;
    }

    private <T> Deserializer<T> getDeserializer(boolean key, MockSchemaRegistryClient mockSchemaRegistryClient) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, "true");
        map.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, registryUrl);
        Deserializer<T> deserializer = (Deserializer) new KafkaAvroDeserializer(mockSchemaRegistryClient);
        deserializer.configure(map, key);
        return deserializer;
    }


}
```

And important, register the schemas to the mocked schema registry:

```
mockSchemaRegistryClient.register(getSubjectName(mappedCdlcfTopic,false),Tracking.getClassSchema());
mockSchemaRegistryClient.register(getSubjectName(logsTopic,false), Log.getClassSchema());
```

Also had to import the `getSubjectName` from the mockedSchema library, in order to generate the same key as they generate, to look up for the schema id.

```
static String getSubjectName(String topic, boolean isKey) {
    return isKey ? topic + "-key" : topic + "-value";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem with kafka stream, TopologyTestDriver and MockSchemaRegistry. I fix it by always providing the key and value serde to the kafka stream topology i tried to test.

exemples :

```
myStream
    .mapValues(value -> MyCustomAvro.newBuilder()
        .setValue1(value.getValue1())
        .setValue2(value.getValue2())
        .build())
    .to("myTopic",Produced.with(Serdes.String(), myCustomSerde));
```

or

```
myStream.groupByKey()
    .aggregate(
        () -> new myCustomAvro(),
        (key, value1, value2) ->  new myCustomAvro(value1, value2),
        Materialized.<String, MyCustomAvro, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(
            "my_custom_table")
            .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
            .withValueSerde(myCustomSerde));
```

This way, it work with internal topics and stores because you can configured myCustomSerde with the MockSchemaRegistryClient during the testing phase. You don't even have to register your topics into the MockSchemaRegistryClient. You only need to configure your serdes like that :

```
SpecificAvroSerde<SpecificRecord> mySerde = new SpecificAvroSerde<>(
    mockSchemaRegistryClient);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to use `mockSchemaRegistryClient`

https://objectpartners.com/2018/08/21/testing-with-spring-kafka-and-mockschemaregistryclient/

Comment: I've already seen that article, but the problem is on Kafka Streams topology, that works like "normal" when is executed with the TopologyTestDriver, it tries to publish the records in a "real topic", when it tries to do so, it goes to the url of the schema registry provided in the properties. So the thing is, how to link the TopologyTestDriver to the mocked schema, to register and retrieve those schemas.

Comment: The problem is, that you use set the AvroSerdes in the config -- if you do this, the AvroSerde don't know about the `MockSchemaRegistry` -- instead, you will need to create the serdes object manually and pass in the MockSchemaRegistry into them. Then you pass in the serdes as object. For example `builder.stream("topic", Consumer.with(serde, serde))`. It's a know issue that the integration with schema registry is not perfect atm and we hope to address this soon.

Comment: Note, that `TopologyTestDriver` is part of Apache Kafka while Schema Registry is part of Confluent Open Source. This makes it a little bit more difficult to get a seamless integration.

Comment: Also check out the docs: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/test-streams.html